# Include Border-radius in php code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to include Border-radius in php code. I'm pasting the below code to display an image in individual pages. i want to display border-radius only in one page. So i want to add the border-radius inside the code only in one page

Code:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '32' ); ?>
```

Comment: The return value already is an `img` element. If you don't want to use Javascript etc. to modify this, you probably should modify or extend the function `get_avatar`. For example add a CSS class there in the output. `get_avatar()` is located in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow different approach. You need to add a class based on the condition and then for the class you give border-radius.

```
.myclass { border-radius: 10px; }
```

If it is loading in div

```
<div class="myclass"><?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '32' ); ?></div>
```

If it is image

```
<img class="myclass" <?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '32' ); ? />
```

Comment: Though this is not the answer to the question, it nails the problem when remarking that the approach of adding style to php code is wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
<div style="border-radius: 10px;">
    <?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '32' ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides the filter `get_avatar` that you can use:

This is pretty much a copy&paste from the [documentation of the filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar):

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 1 , 4 );
function my_custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    $avatar = "<img alt='{$alt}' src='{$avatar}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    return $avatar;
}
```

Just add any class you want to use, add the corresponding class in your CSS.